# How do I stop Scrollviewer from expanding to infinite height?

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

I have a grid, with 3 rows.
Row 2 has a variable height, the window is resizable, and I have a datagrid on Row 3, held within a scrollviewer, within a tabcontrol.

When there are many items in the scrollviewer, the scrollviewer expands until it reaches the "max height" available to it, however that max height is infinity... so it keeps growing and growing. What I want it to do, is stop expanding if that would mean it is pushing the parent grid out of bounds, and instead use its scroll functionality... Here is the general layout of it:

```
<TabControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
    <TabItem Header="Weapons">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <DataGrid>
                ...
            </DataGrid>
         </ScrollViewer>
     </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

That is held within a grid which has 3 rows and 3 columns. There is content in rows 0 and 1 which I didnt put here, and obviously I took out the unnecessary info from Datagrid etc...

Example of what I see:

[image: This is what it turns out like]

As requested, the whole XAML. Not exactly short, which is why I thought the simplified version above would be better. [XAML - Too large to fit in post](http://pastebin.com/EMmn2T9C)

OK, so its there. I am looking at both datagrids held in different tabs of the tabcontrol on Row 2 of the grid.

Condensed "full" xaml:

```
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">

    <Image Source="{StaticResource EmptySlot}" Margin="0" Width="34"/>
    <Image Source="{Binding AuraSlot, FallbackValue={StaticResource AuraSlot}}" Margin="0" Width="34"/>
</Grid>

<Popup AllowsTransparency="True" Placement="Relative" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=MainWindowName}" IsOpen="{Binding WeaponTooltipOpen}" HorizontalOffset="{Binding WeaponOffsetX}" VerticalOffset="{Binding WeaponOffsetY}" PopupAnimation="Fade" OpacityMask="White" >
    ...
</Popup>

<Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">

    <Expander orizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Expander.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="Equipment Slots" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </Expander.Header>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
            ...
        </Grid>

    </Expander>
</Grid>

<TabControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
    <TabItem Header="Weapons">
        <Grid>
            <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" >
                <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedWeapons}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro" AlternationCount="2" RowHeaderWidth="0">
                    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle>
                            ...
                        </GroupStyle>
                    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>

                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        ...
                    </DataGrid.Columns>

                    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                ...
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>

                </DataGrid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>


</TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: What, pray tell, do css and wpf have to do with each other?  And I think you can dump your datagrid directly in the tabitem and do away with the scrollviewer.  The datagrid has a built-in scrollviewer which will work as expected.  Also, css?  Yeah, I'm back on that again.

Comment: Sorry - I clicked it from the recommended tags, reading it as C# in my head not CSS.

The daragrid doesnt scroll itself, as can be seen in screenshot. :(

Comment: WPF DataGrids most certainly do.  You might be doing something else weird...

Comment: That DataGrid does not scroll itself because you have it in a scroll viewer.  Are you going to try suggestions?  And post the grid columns and row definitions.

Comment: I toggled on the setting to have the scroll for Datagrid, but it does the exact same thing as the containing scrollviewer. It reaches the bottom of the window but keeps adding content past that point.

Comment: Look at this http://i.stack.imgur.com/GEdMc.png Took me 30 seconds to prove ya wrong!  This is like my best time ever winning arguments over the internets!  You're doing something else weird if your application isn't exhibiting this behavior.  Strip it down to the bare minimum and start adding stuff back.

Comment: This is what I see when I have it show the scrollbar permanently: http://i.imgur.com/4OTN6fv.jpg - Try putting, in that example, the tabcontrol within a grid, and see it run off the bottom of the screen.

Comment: @MatthewParker you need to post the whole XAML. It looks to me like there is a parent element with a larger height, which the datagrid uses. Without the XAML it is pure guessing though. Check out [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) and look at the red adorners to see which sizes the elements have.

Comment: XAML has been added, but pastebin as its too large. That is the entire grid, with everything inside of it. Row 2 is where my datagrid lives (there are 2 datagrids, both are equally effected and sit in different tabs of the same tabcontrol on row 2)

Comment: @MatthewParker when I said "whole XAML" I actually meant "Short self contained compilable example". Sorry for the confusion but noone is going to read that chunk of code for you. Try to create as short of an example as possible. And again, check out Snoop and see if you find anything there.

Comment: Added condensed XAML.

Comment: I copied your condensed XAML and it does not show the problem you described. It shows the complete scrollbar just fine.

Comment: Does the scrollbar actually scroll if the space for it is too small? If so then I dont know whats going on at all...

Comment: You have a Grid in the Tab with no column or row definitions and then you put DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3". Clean up the code.

Comment: Taken those Grid.Row etc out, but still presents the same problem.

Comment: Rather than a mass of code present the most simple code that reproduces the problem.  And I bet you still have a grid in the tab.   I don't take you at your word.  What you posted in the original question is not even the same as the code once you finally posted it.

Comment: Excuse me? "present the most simple code..." Thats what I did initially. Then I gave everything, and finally simplified it down from there again but leaving more info in. I have taken out that grid, same problem. I dont know what more I can do to present this question?

Comment: Simple and ACCURATE.  Leaving out the Grid changes the question.   Leaving out the Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" changes the question.  Learn to break down a problem.  You include stuff that does not matter and exclude stuff that does matter.  In the link ScrollViewer is commented out.   I bet you still have a messed up second TabItem.  It is not just a poor question but poor problem solving skills.  Strip stuff out and find the cause.   Post the most simple code that will reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, eventually found the problem.

I don't really knwo the reason as to WHY this was the problem, because it doesn't really make sense to me, but WAY up in the code I had things wrapped in a stackpanel. The only 2 things stacked there were a textblock, and a Grid, with the grid containing a ton of other things, including all the code posted along with the question. Taking out that stackpanel made it work correctly, so I have now permanently replaced the stackpanel with another grid, using 2 differnet rows. :)